# In Xcode comparison view, how do you filter for different files only?

Tags: xcode

Say I have a large project in Xcode, with comparison view open to show me the difference between branches/commits. How do I get Xcode's project navigator to show me only those files where such a difference exists?

Answer (score 0):

There are no way.

There are 2 workaround at least:

**1)** Commit:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Then cancel

**2)** Open a terminal, navigate to your project:

```
git diff --name-only
```

Comment: what does --name-only substitute for please?

Comment: "--name-only" list only files that have been modified
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---name-only

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode File Navigator you have this square "git" button on the right hand side.

[image]

You can use it to filter files which git status has changed